# php and javascript cookie

Tags: php, javascript

why php get cookie new value only when i refresh page twice.
When run page first time, php do not get cookie value.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var name = 'test1';
var value = '1234';
var expirydays = '1';
expiry = new Date();
expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + expirydays);
document.cookie = name+"="+escape(value)+";expires="+expiry.toGMTString();
</script>

<?php       
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing how PHP and JavaScript work.

PHP is run first, on server side.

JavaScript is run long after PHP has run, on client side in the user's browser.

A cookie you set in JavaScript will never be visible to the PHP script that generated the Javascript: It is too late. You will have to reload the page.

Incidentally however, even values set through PHP's own `setcookie()` will be visible only after a page reload, because the `$_COOKIE` variable is populated when the script starts.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run on the server, and JavaScript on the client.  The PHP code is run before the JavaScript code is run, so the 1st time, PHP doesn't have the cookie yet.  It works the 2nd time, because the cookie is already there.